# UIImageView displays white in place of the status bar

Tags: iphone, interface-builder

I have set the statusbar to unspecified in IB.

On the app start up the space where the status bar was is white, not allowing my image to fill the screen.

When I return to that View after selecting back from another view. The image is full and he white bar is gone.

Do I have to set the status bar to hidden in the code as well as in IB, or is that set in the info.plist file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try adding UIStatusBarHidden to info.plist set it to bool en enable it..

Comment: Thanks, I just set it to be initially hidden.